# Dropbox Authentication for both PHP and JS SDKs

Tags: dropbox-api

I am writing a web app that will allow a user to migrate their Dropbox Datastore data to a new database file that I will store in their Dropbox account using the core API.

The user authenticates using the PHP SDK, but when I attempt to make a Datastore call via JS, the Dropbox client isn't authenticated.

Is there a way I can grant access to both the PHP core SDK and JS Datastore SDK within the *same* authorization flow? I'd hate for my users to have to authenticate twice (once for each SDK).

Comment: You can re-use access tokens, subject to the permission level granted by the access tokens, between SDKs as long as the SDKs use the same kind of access tokens (i.e., both OAuth 1 or both OAuth 2). Which SDKs/versions are you using specifically?

Comment: I'm using the PHP SDK 1.1.5 and the Datastore JS SDK 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both the [Dropbox Datastore JavaScript SDK v1.2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/datastore/sdks/js) and the [Dropbox PHP Core SDK v1.1.5](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/php) use OAuth 2 access tokens and have constructors that taken an OAuth 2 access token directly.

To create a client in the PHP SDK using an OAuth 2 access token, use this constructor and pass in an OAuth 2 access token as `$accessToken`:

https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-php/api-docs/v1.1.x/class-Dropbox.Client.html#___construct

To create a client in the JavaScript SDK using an OAuth 2 access token, you can use this constructor and pass in an OAuth 2 access token as `token`:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/datastore/docs/js#Dropbox.Client

Remember that a Dropbox OAuth 2 access token is specific to a particular user-app pair, and will only have access to the extent allowed by the permission the app is registered for.